# Reassigning from JS Object A property value to another

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to assign prices to my items from a JSON A to JSON B, managed to get the prices and reassign it to the property but not to the whole object.

here's a snippet of my code, which gets the prices from the first Object and reassigning it to `TotalOrignialValue` however how can I push it back to the `newJson` object?

Is there a more pleasing way of achieving this?

```js
// Code goes here

var items = {
    "TransactionLine": [
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1112"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.35,
      },
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1113"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.15,
      }
    ],
    "CustomData": {}
  };
  
  var itemPrice = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.TransactionLine.length; i++) {
    var el = items.TransactionLine[i];
    itemPrice.push(el.TotalValue);
    console.log(el.TotalValue);
  }
  
  var newJson = {
    "OrderLines": [
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 9,
              "Codes": [
                "1113"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1113"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          },
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 21,
              "Codes": [
                "1112"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1112"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          }
        ]
  };
  
  var newPrice = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < newJson.OrderLines.length; x++) {
    var xd = newJson.OrderLines[x].TotalOriginalValue;
    xd = itemPrice[x];
    newjson = {
      "TotalOriginalValue": xd
    };
    newPrice.push(newjson);
  }

  console.log('newJSON >> ', newPrice);
```

Comment: Just post the expected result and let us do the rest.

Comment: @Kinduser its a very "kind" comment.. but we should try to help in solving not solve ourselves.

Comment: @Minato What's so unpleasant with my comment? I just asked him for a desired result...

Comment: @Kinduser I never said your comment was unpleasant, but it was way too kind..

Comment: @Minato I just thought that it's a sarcasm or something this way (((:

Comment: @Kinduser I forgot (pun intended)and he has posted the desired output if you look into the `newJson` he just needs to assign `totalValue` from `items` to `totalOriginalValue` from `newJson`.

Comment: @Kinduser basically the expected result is the same as the `newJson` just with the price from `items`

Comment: The answer should be `newJson.OrderLines[x].TotalOriginalValue = itemPrice[x];` assuming both the Objects have the same ordering of products.

Comment: @Minato Ah of course :( should have seen that rather than doing pushing to `array[]` again. But will try the other answers as pretty sure there's a faster way rather than doing `for()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your only connection from JSON A to JSON B is the codes array on the items.

You could loop over entries in JSON a, find the corresponding item in JSON B by checking the codes values, and assign the values directly on JSON B entries

```js
var items = {
    "TransactionLine": [
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1112"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.35,
      },
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1113"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.15,
      }
    ],
    "CustomData": {}
  };

var newJson = {
    "OrderLines": [
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 9,
              "Codes": [
                "1113"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1113"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          },
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 21,
              "Codes": [
                "1112"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1112"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          }
        ]
  };
  
items.TransactionLine.forEach(item=>{
    var match = newJson.OrderLines.find(entry=>entry.Product.Codes[0] === item.Product.Codes[0]);
    if (!match) { 
        return;
    }
    match.TotalOriginalValue = item.TotalValue;
});
console.log(newJson);
```

This will also cut out the use of the array and a loop through the items JSON.
On a list of 2 its not so bad, but add a few hundred/thousand and it will become noticeable.

Comment: This loop is assuming that codes is a length 1 array in each product.
You could of course match products by other means if you know what they would be, or have a more complex condition such as match on codes[0] if there, else match on Id, else match on Sku.

And it would also be helpful to add validation to ensure there is a match before trying to assign a value to it

Comment: how about a `forEach` you won't have to do all those new element assignments and indexing mess. just saying..

Comment: a foreach would require that the matching entries are always at the same position in the arrays. If that is guaranteed then a forEach is much more efficient, however, if it cannot be guaranteed then the forEach becomes unreliable.

Comment: you're using `find` it doesn't matter.. does it?

Comment: ah yes, you are correct, I was thinking you meant using it like @Kinduser suggested which is miles faster given the extra requirements.

forEach would be acceptable in most cases, when it comes to larger arrays, forEach becomes inefficient and lodash.forEach becomes the better option, but even so, a for loop will out perform the lodash function after a certain point.

Comment: you are right, but this won't even be noticeable as for me I'll choose `forEach` for ***code readability***.

Comment: I do agree that the forEach is much more readable and the performance is acceptable is almost all situations. Good point :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash makes your life so much easier that does what you need using lodash there is probably an even more succinct way of doing it with it.

```
var items = {
    "TransactionLine": [
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1112"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.35,
      },
      {
        "Product": {
          "Id": null,
          "Codes": [
            "1113"
          ],
          "Sku": null
        },
        "TotalValue": 2.15,
      }
    ],
    "CustomData": {}
  };



  var newJson = {
    "OrderLines": [
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 9,
              "Codes": [
                "1113"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1113"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          },
          {
            "Product": {
              "Id": 21,
              "Codes": [
                "1112"
              ],
              "Sku": "CS1112"
            },
            "TotalOriginalValue": 0, // asign the price here
          }
        ]
  };

var test = _.map(items.TransactionLine, (item,index) => {
return _.set(newJson.OrderLines[index], 'TotalOriginalValue', item.TotalValue)
})

console.log(test)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k6vdyhx7/124/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `OrderLines` key value, which is an array, then replace every `TotalOriginalValue` value with responding value from the `items.TransactionLine` array.

```js
var items = {TransactionLine:[{Product:{Id:null,Codes:["1112"],Sku:null},TotalValue:2.35},{Product:{Id:null,Codes:["1113"],Sku:null},TotalValue:2.15}],CustomData:{}},
    newJson = {OrderLines:[{Product:{Id:9,Codes:["1113"],Sku:"CS1113"},TotalOriginalValue:0},{Product:{Id:21,Codes:["1112"],Sku:"CS1112"},TotalOriginalValue:0}]};
 
    newJson.OrderLines.forEach((v,i) => v.TotalOriginalValue = items.TransactionLine[i].TotalValue);
    console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: This assumes that the position in the arrays are always the same.
Given strict requirements that will be much more efficient, but if that cannot be guaranteed then this becomes unreliable

Comment: @AndyMacleod Looking forward for your solution, dealing with this problem (:

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've edited my post. I hope that it's description satisfy you. (: